# Slick optional query parameters

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using Slick to query a database. I pass a Case class to my query method which looks like similar to...

```
case class queryParams(id:Int, age:Option[Int] = None, 
    categoryId:Option[Int] = None)
```

I have a Slick query that is similar to...

```
val query = this.filter( row => 
  (row.id == queryParams.id))
query.list
```

And this works fine. But what I want to do now is extend the query to include the other queryParams members "if" they are defined but I'm unsure how I should structure this.

What I want is something like this...

```
for { row <- this.list 
    if(row.id == queryParams.id)
    // include
    if(queryParams.age.isDefined) row.age == queryParams.age.get
  } yield row
```

How can I include optional params in the query?

Thanks

Comment: Why the `if`? As soon as you have an option, you can just plug in the option instead of handling that as a special case.

Comment: Hi Reactor. Thats partly my issue. I'm unsure of the syntax required due to my noobishness! :)

Comment: Provide some more code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom "MaybeFilter" solution that is posted in various places including...

See https://gist.github.com/studiodev/5c6471cb1d823914ee28

Comment: that link is a 404